# React filter array of object based on select dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I have a search bar, a drowdown and a filtered list which currently works as it should, but what I want to do is replace 'name' in filterV.product.name with a value selected from a dropdown.

```
 const filterArray = ["name", "description", "condition", "purpose", "category"];
```

one of these values should replace name when the user selects it from the dropdown and searches with the filter on.

```
 {this.state.filteredContent.length > 0 ? this.state.filteredContent.filter((filterV) => {
                        return   filterV.product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
                    }).map((item, index) => (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <ProductItem
                                goToLink={true}
                                delete={false}
                                edit={false}
                                remove={false}
                                duplicate={false}
                                item={item}
                                hideMore
                            />
                        </div>
                    )): null}
```

any help much appriciated.

also even though the filter function is working and displaying the list on screen correctly, when I console.log  this.state.filteredContent the length never changes, any ideas how I can get the correct list of filtered objects?

the list comes throught redux props

```
 this.state = {
        searchValue: '',
        filterValue: '',
        filteredContent: props.productWithoutParentList.length > 0 ? props.productWithoutParentList : [],
    }
```

Comment: `["name", "description", "condition", "purpose", "category"]` is options of dropdown and `product` contains there properties? Would be a lot easier to understand if you could create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes that is correct. I will try to create a reproducible example

Comment: Here is a codesandbox implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wind-owyqk?file=/src/Main.js is that helps. Thanks.

Comment: CodeSandBox Link https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wind-owyqk?file=/src/Main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the filter using `[]` dynamic property access notation:

```
{this.state.filteredContent
        .filter((filterV) => {
          return (
            filterV.product[this.state.filterValue]
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(this.state.searchValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
          );
        })
```

Note that I've also set a default value of `filterValue: "name"`

[image: Edit condescending-liskov-wiqxn]

Comment: Any idea why once filtered the length of the state.filteredContent remains the same?

Comment: @Zinox you're never really updating `state.filteredContent`, `Array.filter()` returns a new filtered array, you're using that one for rendering. It gets created and thrown away during the rendering process

Comment: Do remember that if you decide to update it, you'll need a copy of original so that when filters reset, you can put everything back...

Comment: Ofcouse. thank you for the reminder. :) I keep forgetting filter returns a new array